# How do I activate the Cheat Mod in Zombes ModPack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I recently installed Zombes Mod Pack on Minecraft. I know that I installed it correctly because the other mod I enabled that lets me reach farther does work. I then moved onto the cheat mod and set it up like I set up the other.

I had Minecraft closed at the time and when I started up Minecraft again, there was no error. I then checked what the key to activate Cheat Mode multiple times, but when I hit it it would not turn on, therefore I can't see the part I activated.

Is there something I am doing wrong? I have uncommented the mod and each thing I wanted, and I removed all the spaces. My only worry is that the key controls I entered were wrong and unrecognized.

Here is my config folder:
[image: Here is my config folder showing how I set up the Cheat Mod:]

Comment: Perhaps if you posted your configuration file we could better tell what the problem is?

Comment: If you don't already, turn the info mod on and try turning on cheat again. If it works, then the word "cheat" should appear in the top left. Also, is there any other mod bound to the 'R' key? I think the wield mod uses 'R' by default...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have uncommented some lines that should have remained as comments.  "Uncomment to enable mod" actually refers to the line below it ("modCheatEnabled       = yes").

Every time there's a blank line, the first line afterwards is a brief description of what the option does and so should remain as a comment.

So, for example, the first couple of lines originally look like this:

```
# Uncomment to enable mod:
#modCheatEnabled       = yes
```

You changed it so it looks like this:

```
Uncomment to enable mod:
modCheatEnabled       = yes
```

But it should actually look like this:

```
# Uncomment to enable mod:
modCheatEnabled       = yes
```

The "modCheatEnabled" line should be the ONLY line you remove a '#' from in the Cheat Mod section of the config.  I noticed that several other options (presumably all the options you changed) have been uncommented in the same way.  "Toggles Cheat mode on / off", "Show / hide ores", "See through everything nearby..." and all the other lines that look like descriptions should still be commented with a '#' sign in front of them.  It's the lines below those comments ("keyCheatShowOres      = C", "keyCheatSee           = T", etc.) that actually do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to save the config file before you started up minecraft? Also I think "Uncomment to enbale mod" should still have a #.

Comment: I changed it to what you said, but it still didn't work. The main thing I want in this is the OreFinder, but I don't know what I'm looking for; I went and found some coal, but after hitting both 'S' and 'C' multiple repeating times, I didn't see a change. I also made sure that there were no Minecraft controls set for 'S' or 'C'. Is there anything else that needs to be done OVERALL, because I haven't changed anything else but the cheat mod.

Comment: You know you have to hit R to turn cheat mode on and off right? There should be some notification that it is on or off, somewhere up in the top left of the screen probably.

Comment: Yah, I know. I have also tried changing it to other keys.